# How to calculate the logarithm of a number in MASM 32

Tags: assembly, x86, logarithm, masm32, fpu

How do I calculate the logarithm of a number in MASM 32?
For example if I have to calculate log(2.5), how will I do this?
I know this will involve `fyl2x` and I have tried but I couldn't calculate it accurately.

This is what I tried but it prints no result.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

; .data is used for declaring and defining variables
.data
num     real8 3.324          ; the data I want to convert
res     real8 ?              

   .code
   main PROC

    fldl2t               ; st: log2(10)
    fld num              ; st: log2(10) num
    fyl2x                ; st: log10(num)
    fstp res             ; store to out and pop


    call    CrLf
    call    CrLf

exit    
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: log(x) = log2(x) / log2(e). `FLDL2E` loads log2(e) onto the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have copied the code from [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680745/how-to-count-log-and-ln-in-masm-assembly/52682160#52682160). Sadly, that answer contains errors!

Before using the `FYL2X` instruction, read the description in the manual:

> This instruction calculates (ST(1)*log<sub>2</sub>(ST(0))), stores the result in register ST(1), and pops the FPU register stack. The source operand in ST(0) must be a non-zero positive number.

> The `FYL2X` instruction is designed with a built-in multiplication to optimize the calculation of logarithms with an arbitrary positive base (*b*).
> log<sub>b</sub>x = (log<sub>2</sub>b)<sup>-1</sup> * log<sub>2</sub>x

The error stems from not noticing that the multiplier is a reciprocal. We can easily remove it because (log<sub>2</sub>b)<sup>-1</sup> = log<sub>b</sub>2 and then we substitute 10 for *b*. We therefore need as multiplier log<sub>10</sub>2 which the FPU provides through its `FLDLG2` instruction.

```
num     REAL8 3.324
res     REAL8 ?

        ...

        FLDLG2           ; ST0 = log10(2)
        FLD     num      ; ST1 = log10(2), ST0 = num
        FYL2X            ; ST0 = log10(num)
        FSTP    res
```

To calculate the natural logarithm (aka 'ln'), the only change would be to use `FLDLN2` (instead of `FLDLG2`) to obtain the multiplier log<sub>e</sub>2.

To calculate the binary logarithm, the only change would be to use `FLD1` (instead of `FLDLG2`) to obtain the trivial multiplier 1.

---

An algorithm that converts a floating point number into its textual representation is not all that simple, but maybe next fixed-point trick is all that you need:

- multiply the floating point number by 1000 (for a 3-digit precision)
- store the product to memory **as integer**
- convert (*) the integer into text (repeated divisions by 10)
- put a decimal point character between the last 3 digits and all the digits in front of them

```
num     REAL8 3.324
quad    dq ?
kilo    dw 1000

        ...

        FLDLG2           ; ST0 = log10(2)
        FLD     num      ; ST1 = log10(2), ST0 = num
        FYL2X            ; ST0 = log10(num)
        FIMUL   kilo     ; ST0 = 1000 * log10(num)
        FISTP   quad
        ...
```

(*) [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) explains how converting an integer to text works. Look through the 'with DOS' mention and focus on the how and the why of the conversion itself.

Answer (score 0):

The log conversion formula is log_b(x) = log_d(x)/log_d(b) or alternatively

log_b(x)*log_d(b) = log_d(x)

In your case I assume b = 2 and d = 10. So you want to push log_10(2) instead of log_2(10) onto the stack, since fyl2x compute SP(1) * log_2(SP(0)).

The command is FLDLG2 instead of FLDL2T.

Comment: okay I have done that, but how do I print out the final value from the register

Comment: Ok, sorry. This is much more complex, as you have to convert your float to a string. You can look at this example: https://gist.github.com/nikAizuddin/c2d5cfad8c6abe5bd2ed

You might also want to consider using the c or c++ ABI and use a higher level language for printing, as this can become tedious very quickly.