# How to get fractional part? ( modf() Intel assembly equivalent )

Tags: assembly, sse, x87

Is there a **single** assembly instruction that gets the fractional part of a double or float (or packed double or float)?

(x87 x64 SSE)

Comment: You have asked *at least* 3 different questions in this very short text. How to get the fractional part, how to implement `modf`, and whether there exists a *single instruction* to get the fractional part. Also both x87 and SSE are involved somehow in a way that is not quite clear. What is your actual question?

Comment: No I don't want to implement modf. I also don't want to round/truncate (FRNDINT) than subtract.

Comment: If the main question is "is there a *single instruction* that gets the fractional part", the answer is no there isn't. Not even FPREM.

Comment: AVX512F has `vgetmantpd/ps` to get the mantissa (as a `double` / `float` normalized to your choice of ranges), but that's not the same thing as the fractional part.  https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VGETMANTPD.html https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VGETMANTPS.html.  There's a `vgetexppd` as well.  They're useful for implementing log2().

Comment: Oh, (off topic) log2() is important to me , do you have a link to this algorithm/ implementation ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770089/efficient-implementation-of-log2-m256d-in-avx2.

Comment: @harold `vfrcz(s/p)(s/d)` in XOP and `vreduce(s/p)(s/d)` in AVX512-DQ will do it in a single instruction. Neither of these are readily available though.

Comment: ^^ /cc @PeterCordes

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about [`vreducepd`](https://hjlebbink.github.io/x86doc/html/VREDUCEPD.html).  Thanks, @Mysticial.  I didn't know about the XOP instruction.  I think you can at least test AVX512DQ instructions using Intel's SDE emulator, if you don't have a Skylake-avx512 CPU.