# AVX/SSE convert floating point sign mask to __m128i

Tags: c, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm using the following to extract the sign bit of an `__mm128`:

```
const int sign_mask = _mm_movemask_ps(a);
```

I now want to use the following to blend two vectors:

```
v_add = _mm_blendv_ps(a, v_add_neg, _mm_castsi128_ps(v_mask));
```

`v_mask` needs to come from `sign_mask` but I cannot find an intrinsic that does this.

The code's purpose is to change the signs of `a` vector's elements based on the signs in another vector's corresponding elements.

Comment: You could store all the possible v_masks in an array, indexed by the sign_mask. But I don't see why you want to go through sign_mask, you should stick to vectors.

Comment: I subsequently figured it's easier to use vector AND and OR to do this. There isn't an intrinsic (that I know of) that extracts the sign into a vector.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need such an intrinsic, because `_mm_blendv_ps (a, b,c)` uses the sign bits of `c` to choose between the elements of `a` and `b`. Probably that is just want you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `_mm_blendv_ps(a, v_add_neg, a)`.  `blendvps` takes a *vector* input, and uses the sign bit of each element as the blend condition for that element.

You only need movemask if you need it as an integer, *not* a vector, e.g. to use it as an index for a lookup table, or to branch on all vector elements having some property for example.

> The code's purpose is to change the signs of a vector's elements based on the signs in another vector's corresponding elements.

**Use booleans to manipulate sign bits**:

```
 // pick your favourite way to express a 0x80000000 FP constant: just the sign bit set.
__m128  sign_v = _mm_and_ps(v, _mm_set1_ps(-0.0));
__m128  a_times_sign_v = _mm_xor_ps(a, sign_v);
```

The flips the sign of elements in `a` where `v` had its sign bit set.

Note that it treats `-0.0` as negative, not zero, and `-NaN` is also treated as a normal negative.  If you don't want that, use `_mm_cmplt_ps` and left-shift or AND that compare-mask to get a sign-bit mask for `xorps`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169913/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-cordes-avx-sse-convert-floating-point-sign-mask-to).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what library do you use for Log and Exp on pd's?

Comment: @IamIC: last time I needed it, I was using Agner Fog's Vector Class Library (http://agner.org/optimize/), which is GPLed.  But I needed a fast approximation to Log() for packed `float`, so I did some research and made a very fast version that was accurate enough for my purposes (as part of `asinh`).  See [Efficient implementation of log2(\_\_m256d) in AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787548) for an overview of what I used (JRF's polynomial of order 6, with AVX2 FMA).  I haven't had a need for packed-`double` or an accurate Log that's anywhere near 1 or 0.5 ulp precision.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. You're amazingly helpful as always.

Comment: (Update on my previous comment, VCL is now licensed with an Apache license, not GPL)